# how to increase waiting time for response in php?

Tags: php, jquery, apache, joomla, server

I have a php script in joomla component. There are in this script amount items that this items is selected and pressed report button.

Then an AJAX request send to server and in server side generate an excel file.

Due to huge large data, generating excel file takes **about 2 minutes**, but after sending an AJAX request **only 30 second** the request timeout ends and AJAX request **returned nothing**.

How can I increase the waiting time response from 30 second to 5 minutes?

this is javascript that send AJAX request to server. i set timeout 300000 but my problem was not resolved.

```
function AJAX(url, dataSend, target) {
result = jQuery.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: url,
    data: dataSend,
    timeout: 300000,
    async: false,
    processData:false,
    traditional:true,
    beforeSend: function() {
        jQuery('.displayBodyWaiting').show();
    },
    success: function() {
        jQuery('.displayBodyWaiting').hide();
    }
}).responseText;
return result;}
```